# How to make a Ext.js 4 grid plugin stateful?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I found a ext.js grid plugin for changing page size via a combo box. from here ([enter link description here](http://www.elvishsu66.com/2011/05/pagesize-plugin-for-paging-toolbar-for.html#.U2ca0PmSwjU))

This is the plugin

```
/**
* Ext.ux.grid.PageSize
*/
Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.PageSize', {
    extend      : 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias       : 'plugin.pagesize',
    beforeText  : 'Show',
    afterText   : 'rows/page',
    mode        : 'local',
    displayField: 'text',
    valueField  : 'value',
    allowBlank  : false,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    width       : 50,
    maskRe      : /[0-9]/,    
    /**
    * initialize the paging combo after the pagebar is randered
    */
    init: function(paging) {
        paging.on('afterrender', this.onInitView, this);
    },
    /**
    * create a local store for availabe range of pages
    */
    store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['text', 'value'],
        data: [['5', 5], ['10', 10], ['15', 15], ['20', 20], ['25', 25], ['50', 50], ['100', 100], ['200', 200], ['500', 500]]
    }),    
    /**
    * assing the select and specialkey events for the combobox 
    * after the pagebar is rendered.
    */
    onInitView: function(paging) {
        this.setValue(paging.store.pageSize); 
        paging.add('-', this.beforeText, this, this.afterText);
        this.on('select', this.onPageSizeChanged, paging);
        this.on('specialkey', function(combo, e) {
            if(13 === e.getKey()) {
                this.onPageSizeChanged.call(paging, this);        
            }
        });
    },
    /**
    * refresh the page when the value is changed
    */
    onPageSizeChanged: function(combo) {
        this.store.pageSize = parseInt(combo.getRawValue(), 10);
        this.doRefresh();
    }
});
```

I want add the combo box state to grid state so that the grid shows last changed page size on reload. (I need to add the value to the grids state item not to separate state item)

How can I do that in **Ext.JS 4.*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include the `Ext.state.Stateful` mixin and override the [`getState()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.state.Stateful-method-getState) method:

```
getState: function(){
    return this.store.pageSize;
}
```

and the [`applyState()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.state.Stateful-method-applyState) method:

```
applyState: function(state) {
    if (state) {
        this.store.pageSize = state;
    }
}
```

then if you use this plugin you need to set `stateful` to `true` and give your plugin instance a `stateId`

Comment: the `this` in getState and applyState refers to the combo box itself. and doesn't work this way

Comment: ok then you need to get a reference of the grid: try `this.up('grid').getStore()`

Comment: sorry, but this solution didn't meet my requirements.
I need to add the state to the grid's state item. but this way it added as a separate state item in local storage.

Comment: so what are your requirements?

Comment: I need to append the plugin state to the grid's state. Not as a separate state item in local storage.

Comment: ok thats more complicated: you need to override applyState/getState in the grid and add a custom state param to the grid state data if the plugin is present